# Unexpected results from a simple code

Tags: c++, while-loop

> Q) Write a program to accept the age of n employees and count the
>   number of persons in the following age group: (i)26-35
>   (ii)36-45
>  (iii)46-55

I wrote this program:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main(){
 clrscr();
 unsigned int a, i,ii,iii,ch;
 while(1){
  cout<<"Enter age: ";
  cin>>a;
  if(a>=26 && a<=35){i++;};
  if(a>=36 && a<=45){ii++;};
  if(a>=46 && a<=55){iii++};
  cout<<"continue...[0/1]: ";
  cin>>ch;
  if(!ch){break;}else{continue;};
 };
cout<<"26-35: "<<i<<"/n 36-45: "<<ii<<"\n 45-55: "<<iii;
return 0;
};
```

the first version of this program include `goto` statements rather that `while` loop but the fact is that the results were wrong in both the cases.

the answers were after running this code:

26-35: 1515
36-45: 1539
46-55: 1

here you can see that only the last age group count is correct because i entered  27, 37 and 54 only once when the code was running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Initialize `i=0,ii=0,iii=0`.
   You have forgot to initialize them.(This is the reason for wrong answer)
2. Don't use redundant extra logic.
   `else {continue;}`. You don't need it.